# Difference in MVC & MVP interms of code in c#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, mvp

when we search Google for difference between MVC and MVP then thousand of article is available but i read few but they are not showing difference in terms of coding sample. so if anyone knows any url from where i can see a sample code for both MVC & MVP implementation then please tell me the url. i want basically small sample code by which shown the difference through coding flow in c#. i hope i am very much clear what i am looking for.....i need code same code one with mvc coding flow and another with MVP. i am not asking for theoretical explanation.

Comment: just download the sample projects. first one is for the mvc and the second one is for the mvp, then u cna easxily understang the diff b/w mvp and mvc architecture. This is very simple and sufficient to understand the basic diffrence between both of them.

Answer (score 1):

I also don't have sample code on my blog post "[MVVM vs MVP vs MVC: The differences explained](http://joel.inpointform.net/software-development/mvvm-vs-mvp-vs-mvc-the-differences-explained/)" but I do have a section for each architecture that discusses how to implement them using words.  I will describe it here.

MVP requires a few implementation details

1. Each view must implement an interface for the view (eg IUserEditView for editing users).  This interface contains functions for things that the presenter might need to do (eg, showUsers(IList users), displayMessage(String errorMsg)
2. A presenter is created for each view.  It contains functions that the view will need to call (eg, saveNewUser(User user), selectedUserChanged(User user))
3. An instance of the presenter is created in the view's codebehind.  When view events occur, appropriate messages are forwarded to the the instance of the presenter. eg, when the save button is clicked, all the user details are forwarded to the presenter in the form of a new user....myPresenter.saveNewUser(new User(txtUserName.text, txtPassword.text))
4. When the instance of the presenter is created in (3), the view is passed as an argument to the constructor.  This way, the presenter can reference the IUserEditView from (1)

That is the meat of MVP.  You will probably need to implement the mediator pattern and have all the presenters inherit from base presenter.  This way, presenters can send messages to each other without having to reference each other explicitly which is important (eg, if a new user is added, maybe you need to update a related view like users online).

MVC is a bit more tricky.

1. The controllers have a method of selecting which view is displayed.  This could be referencing just a dictionary of instances of all the views but a better way is to have some class outside the controller manage the details and then the controller can just select the view with something like ShowView("UsersView", listOfUsers).  Note the separate class can be a base class, or a factory, helper
2. A method of forwarding actions from the views to appropriate controllers.  With the web, you just can determine the controller & method from the request url (eg, http://www.mysite.com/mycontroller/method, www.mysite.com/Users/AddNew/).  For other systems, you will have to implement a class to manage the messages, or just directly forward them to an instance of the controller in the view.  I've only used MVC with the web so I'm not so sure about the last point.
3. Because of (2), the view is now able to trigger actions in the controller.  When it does so, the controller modifies the model (the implementation of this will depend on the details of your model).
4. Updates to the model get sent to the view (usually via an observer pattern).  Check out INotifyPropertyChanged if using .net

Word of caution: Although I have described how to implement both methods, they should not really be considered interchangeable.  There are cases when you want MVC, MVP, and MVVM.  I think if you don't have technology limitations around using MVVM, then it is your best choice.  I am biased but I think maybe people are moving away from MVC and towards MVVM (or MVP) except for very specific cases like ASP.NET MVC.  My article describes this in more detail if you need clarification.

Short summary for when to use each in terms of C#

- WinForms -> MVP
- WPF -> MVVM
- ASP -> MVC (if you can't use ASP.NET
  MVC, then MVP will work too)